# MongoDB Dynamic Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, sails.js

I'm new to MongoDB and I would like to get some advice about how to design my database schema.

I'm currently trying to develop a private Events manager using the Sails.js framework for Node.js
Each users of the application will be able to create events and manage guests for each one.

Design #1: (similar to what I would do with MYSQL)
2 collections: users and guests.
Guests are linked to users using a foreign key guest_id

Design #2:
1 users collection using embedded documents

```
{
    "id": "integer",
    "name": "string",
    "guests": [
        {
            "id": "integer",
            "firstname": "string",
            "lastname": "string",
            "attended": "boolean",
            "email": "string",
            "phone": "string",
            "addresse": {
                "street": "string",
                "zipcode": "integer",
                "city": "string",
                "country": "string",
            },
            "notes": "text"
        }
    ],
```

Design #3:
2 collections: Users and Guests.
In guests, each document has an ID and a arrays of people

Design #4:
Using dynamic collections
Each user's guests will be store in one collection named guests_$userid
The thing is I don't know if I can do it with Sails.js

Thank you in advance for your help.
I really want to learn the good practice when designing NoSQL databases and be sure to understand and use all the potential of it.

Comment: To start designing and evluating schema designs, write down what you;re going to do with the data (just in plain english). How will you read it? How will you insert new data? What will you update? What is the most common operation? What needs to be fast? What can you tolerate being slow? With this information we can evaluate different options and pick a best candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 1 - 3 with sails/waterline

You can do 4, but not with waterline, you would have to use a different ORM

As far as the rest of your question goes, it is subject to many variables and is pretty much opinion based.

Comment: You're right about the question being opinion-based. Which is why it's best to close this type of question. There's no way to objectively answer it with a single right answer.

Comment: I can not close someone else's question, in the mean time I offered the best non-opinion answer I could,

Comment: It's not primarily opinion based. The data model is adapted to the use case, and the fitness of a particular data model for a particular use case is a legitimate topic.